# Wordpress not including pages in search

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The WP search functionality is only returning posts, not pages.

I think it's an issue with my WP theme. I have another WP site where it's fine.

One solution here suggested this in functions.php:

```
// include pages in search
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

That works, but it causes my admin searches in the media library to turn up zero results. Any way to restrict the above to front end searches?

Or maybe there's something I can look for in the theme that could be causing this? It's a premium theme, complex, not obvious to me where to look. (my support has expired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function filter_search($query) {

  if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('post','page'));
   }

   return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','filter_search');
```